# Fill Multiselect with List <Objects> or List<Map<String, String>>

Tags: flutter, dart, multi-select

Maybe someone has gone through the same thing, I am trying to fill a Multiselect with the data of a List of my Class Object, but it does not allow me

```
List <Users> _datasource = ...(get data)
...
MultiSelect(
  dataSource: _datasource,
  textField: 'name',
  valueField: 'id'
  .... )
```

I have seen that the datasource that it accepts is of the type: `List<Map<String,String>>`, but I don't know how to convert my `List<Users> to List<Map<String,String>>`, someone maybe you have happened and can collaborate with me.

```
 class UserModel {
  UserModel({
    this.id,
    this.name = '',
  });
  String id;
  String name;
  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserModel(
        id: json["id"].toString(),
        name: json["name"],
      );
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
      };
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey, can you show us what your Users model looks like?

Comment: Sure!
    class UserModel {
        UserModel ({
            this.id,
            this.name = '',
        });
    
        String id;
        String name;
    
        factory UserModel .fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserModel (
            id: json["id"].toString(),
            name: json["name"],
        );
    
        Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
            "id": id,
            "name": name,
        };
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try mapping through your users' list and convert it to a `List<Map<String,String>>`. Something like:

```
var data = _datasource.map((user) => user.toJson()).toList();
});

MultiSelect(
  dataSource: data,
  textField: 'name',
  valueField: 'id'
  .... )
```

Comment: That way if Multiselect worked for me!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your `List<User>` to a `List<Map<String, String>>` :

```dart
List<User> users = ...(get data)
List<Map<String, String>> datasource = users.map((user) => {user.id: user.name}).toList();
// Or using spread operator :
List<Map<String, String>> datasource = [...users.map((user) => {user.id: user.name})];
// Or using collection for :
List<Map<String, String>> datasource = [for (final user in users) {user.id: user.name}]
```

Comment: This option was close, but I did not manage to generate the List that the Multiselect uses.
However, I think it will work for another function, I did not understand the .map
Thanks!